# Prestashop 1.4.3 I need to get a database value and use it in MailAlerts module

Tags: database, prestashop

I have asked this question on the Prestashop forum, but haven't had a reply as of yet.

I need to be able to add a sagepay code to the new order email used in mailalert module.

What I have is;

```
// Filling-in vars for email
$template = 'new_order';
$subject = $this->l('New order');
$spvtxc = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS("SELECT vendortxcode FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."sagepay_transactions` WHERE id_cart = '$order->id_cart'");
...
$templateVars = array(
'{firstname}' => $customer->firstname,
'{lastname}' => $customer->lastname,
...
'{sagepay_no}' => $spvtxc,
...
 );
```

Every time i test a transaction the $spvtxc returns 'ARRAY'.
I have tried;

```
$spvtxc = '5';
```

As Expected this returns 5 as the sagepay number, so I'm confident the variables are being called and added to the email.
And I tried;

```
$spvtxc = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS("SELECT vendortxcode FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."sagepay_transactions` WHERE id_cart = '2'");
```

So this should set $spvtxc to the value that is definatly there (i manually added it in the database), but this still returned 'ARRAY'.

If anyone can point out what I have missed, it is greatly appriceated.

Answer (score 1):

As I was only needing to return a single value, I should have used getValue function instead of ExecuteS.

```
$spvtxc = Db::getInstance()->getValue("SELECT vendortxcode FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."sagepay_transactions` WHERE id_cart = '$order->id_cart'");
```

This returned the value.